# Internal Token Transfer without ETH fee

Tags: tokens, erc-20, cpp-ethereum, address.transfer

Need to move all token from one address to another address(Internal) without fees. Could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Please specify the situation. What tokens? From where to where? Who is owner of the contract?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, any and every transaction on the Ethereum blockchain requires the caller to pay transaction fees.

Transaction fees are calculated as the amount of `gas` required to complete the operation, multiplied by the `gas price` in Ether.

All transactions have a minimum transaction fee of 21,000 gas, and it may be more if you are interacting with a smart contract, like the one that manages the token you want to transfer.

Use a tool like [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) to determine the lowest gas price you will be able to get away with. Note that a gas price of 0 is valid, which would make the whole transaction cost 0 ETH, however, it is likely to be ignored by miners who's incentive is to choose transactions which will pay the most.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Tokens by (if they are your tokens):
[ERC865](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865)